# Azure Machine Learning: Remove pre-installed R packages

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am facing a problem while running my R script in Azure Machine Learning where I am getting the error for Rcpp package:

object '.rcpp_warning_recorder' not found

Searching on SO it seems like it could be an issue to be resolved by upgrading Rcpp tp latst version. AML's Rcpp version is 11.2 while latest on CRAN is 12.0. Does anyone know if pre-installed packages in AML can be updated to latest verson?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a new version of the package as a .zip file. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/2014/09/24/how-to-upload-an-r-package-to-azure-machine-learning.aspx) for instructions. Then you can specify the path to this version when using library() function to pick up the version you want.